# PHP - access json data sent by Matlab via webwrite function

Tags: php, json, matlab

I am using the *webwrite* function in Matlab R2015b to pass on some structured information as a json media type into a PHP script on my server. The matlab code runs without error, however I do not know how to access the information in the PHP script to work with it and first of all to check if the data was transmitted correctly.

Here is a simple example of my Matlab code:

```
data = struct('userId', 20 ,'Password', 10);    
url = 'http://example.info/php/test.php';

options = weboptions('MediaType', 'application/json');
response = webwrite(url, data, options);
```

Now i tried several things in PHP most of them included some usage of the php command json_decode like:

```
$data = json_decode($data,true);
```

However, I do not know how Matlab passes on the information and how to properly access it.

Many thanks for any hints.

Comment: use print_r($data) to see how the array is structured and then you can know what to do. That or ready the Matlab API docs. They must have one... http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: my problem is to get the transferred data into the php variable $data in the first place. I am writing my own "RESTful webservice and want to post data to it from matlab in a structured format and then utilize the data in a php script.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to this problem and wanted to share it in case someone else comes across the same issue:

First of all a slight adjustment had to be made in the Matlab code to include the content type json as well

```
data = struct('userId', 20 ,'Password', 10);    
url = 'http://example.info/php/test.php';

options = weboptions('MediaType','application/json','ContentType','json');
response = webwrite(url, data, options);
```

The php code then looks as follows:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

if($data !== FALSE) {
    echo json_encode($data); //echo same data as check
}
else {
    echo 'Error parsing data';
}
```

Key was to use ***'php://input'*** to address the information passed on by Matlab.